# Who implemented and operates/maintains the user Community?

Tags: support

I'm talking about [this fella](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

I know it's a bot (?), but how is it implemented, who maintains it?

Comment: Start with https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=community+bot and then try the same search on the SO Meta pages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SE developers implemented and maintain it.  Note that it is the same on all SE sites, so this question presumably belongs on meta.SE, not here (it is almost certainly a duplicate, however).  The place to start is: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/187282)  From there, you can read through the threads tagged with [community-user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-user).